# Azure Functions w/ EF Core DbContext - how does the DI scope work?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, azure-functions, transactionscope

**SOLVED**: This error came from a table being locked through the open transaction and the other function call tried to wait for the unlock until it timed out.

I'm currently working on an Azure Function app in .NET Core and trying to add transactions for requests. The problem is, when a function call is doing work between a `context.Database.BeginTransaction(...)` call and a `transaction.CommitAsync(...)` call, then another function call can not save to the database and gets a timeout:

```
[2024-01-04T07:23:29.957Z] An exception occurred in the database while saving changes for context type 'MyContext'.
[2024-01-04T07:23:29.957Z] System.InvalidOperationException: An exception has been raised that is likely due to a transient failure.
[2024-01-04T07:23:29.957Z]  ---> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateException: An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
[2024-01-04T07:23:29.958Z]  ---> Npgsql.NpgsqlException (0x80004005): Exception while reading from stream
[2024-01-04T07:23:29.958Z]  ---> System.TimeoutException: Timeout during reading attempt
```

This other function call can save perfectly fine, when the "long running" function call is not being called beforehand. So I suppose the open transaction is blocking the `DbContext` in other function calls.

Our `DbContext` gets registered like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContext<MyContext>(
    options => options
        .UseNpgsql(dbConnStr)
        .UseSnakeCaseNamingConvention());
```

From what I understand each function call should get its own dependency injection scope, just like in ASP .NET Core, where the "same" setup works without any problems.

Am I missing something?

**EDIT:** I've found someone with the same problem buried in an old Github issue: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/5098#issuecomment-896712016 but there doesn't seem to be a followup with a solution.

**EDIT 2:**

Basic outline of the 2 functions (`_dbContext` gets injected with ctor):

```cs
public class LongerRunningFunctionClass {
    [Function("LongerRunningFunction")]
    public HttpResponseData LongerRunningFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext) {
        await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    
        try {
            // Imagine some code here inserting data into the database
            // and doing calls to external services
    
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception) {
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
            throw;
        }
    } 
}


public class OtherFunctionClass {
    [Function("OtherFunction")]
    public HttpResponseData OtherFunction([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req, FunctionContext executionContext) {
        await using var transaction = await _dbContext.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
    
        try {
            // Imagine a quick insert here
    
            await transaction.CommitAsync();
        }
        catch (Exception) { // <-- I fall into this catch when the other function is still executing with above error
            await transaction.RollbackAsync();
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, first off all,  I really don't think keeping a transaction dangling for a time that could be considered "long running" is a good idea to begin with.

Comment: I understand where you are coming from, but it's just over a few seconds.

Comment: Did you try durable functions? [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-overview?tabs=in-process%2Cnodejs-v3%2Cv1-model&pivots=csharp)

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya how would durable functions help me here?

Comment: Durable function provides parallel execution. so when 1 call is waiting another call can execute.

Comment: @MaximilianRiegler can you share your function code?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya I can share the general outline, but it boils down to what I wrote initially.

Comment: @MaximilianRiegler please share the general outline. I would like to give it a try, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Follow [Use dependency injection in .NET Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-dependency-injection).  Your function methods should not be static, and your function class should have a constructor that accepts your registered DbContext type, eg

```
public class LongerRunningFunctionClass 
{
   MyDbContext _dbContext;

   public LongerRunningFunctionClass(MyDbContext dbContext)
   {
       _dbContext = dbContext;
   }
   public HttpResponseData LongerRunningFunction ...
```

Comment: Thank you for trying. The function method body is copied from the [official documentation (they are using static apparently)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-your-first-function-visual-studio) and just an outline to get the general idea across. I think I'm on my own with this problem from what I could gather the last hours.

Comment: "another function call can not save to the database and gets a timeout:"  This is because you're using static methods, so they share a DbContext instance and when using a Transaction a single database connection.  You need to either not use static methods, or create and dispose the DbContext in each method.

Comment: As I said before - the code posted is merely for demonstration purposes. The actual functions in our project are neither static nor called "LongerRunningFunction". I understand why you answered the question like this. I have now removed the "static" keyword in my example code and added a note on how the `DbContext` is injected.

Comment: You should be able to work around the issue by using a local DbContext instance in each method.  If that doesn't work, there's something else going on.

Comment: Creating a local scope helped me debug this further - thanks. It seems it's just a table lock by PostgreSQL. We'll have to rethink how our functions are supposed to execute or how consistent the data needs to be. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

This error came from a table being locked through the open transaction and the other function call tried to wait for the unlock until it timed out.

Big thanks to David Browne below helping me debug this.

We'll need to rethink either how consistent our data needs to be and if we need the transaction and/or if we can offload some stuff to a queue.